# Laravel doesn't finish controller method on multiple requests

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation, request

I tried to solve multiple clicking on the submit button by using ReCaptcha V3. It kind of works as the database insert only run once in the controller and the following times it just hit the validation returning an error.

**The issue is that the controller method is not entirely run.**

For example if I click multiple times on a submit button on an e-commerce page, in the `CheckoutController`, the `checkout` method doesn't run completely.

```
class CheckOutController extends Controller {

    public function checkout(Request $request) {
        // Some checkout Logic (insert into database)
        $this->validate($request, [
                'recaptcha' => ['required', new \App\Rules\Recaptcha]
            ]);
        if (Cart::content()->count() > 0) {
            foreach (Cart::content() as $cartItem) {
              $insert = new \App\Transaction;
              $insert->product_id = $cartItem->id;
              $insert->receipt_id = $cartItem->receipt_id;
              $insert->quantity = $cartItem->qty;
              $insert->price= $cartItem->price;
              $insert->save();
            }
         Cart::destroy(); //last part of checkout logic
        return view('finishCheckout');
        }
        return abort(404);  
    }
}
```

Because I'm working locally the speed is faster so the request is iterating through my code inserting the data into my database.

**Sometimes the request hits the `Cart:: destroy();` part of the logic, sometimes it doesn't.** But I suspect that on a production environment the code might stop elsewhere before that part.

And it never hits the `return view('finishCheckout');`. It just retrying the same method and fails the validation, returning me back to the checkout page with the validation error.

**Is there anything I can do to ensure that either all the method is run or stop it from running completely?**

Edit:
Note that this only happens when I click the submit buttons multiple times! If I would click it only once, the method runs correctly.

Comment: Any errors logged anywhere?

Comment: I am working with `APP_DEBUG=true` but I have no error in the laravel.log regarding this controller.

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your problem but `Cart::destroy;` is not valid. If you're intending to call a `destroy` static method then you want to do `Cart::destroy();`

Comment: Yes is `Cart::destroy()` in my code. I wrote it here wrong sorry.

Comment: Might be helpful if you could share the code that fails **or** just add lot's of logging after each line to determine what runs and where it stops

Comment: I wrote the code that fails. Only the  `Cart::destroy(); //last part of checkout logic
        return view('finishCheckout');` fails and the rest runs correctly. And the Cart::destroy() only fails sometimes not all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using php transactions like:

```
class CheckOutController extends Controller {

    public function checkout(Request $request) {
        // Some checkout Logic (insert into database)
        $this->validate($request, [
        'recaptcha' => ['required', new \App\Rules\Recaptcha]
        ]);

        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            if (Cart::content()->count() > 0) {
                foreach (Cart::content() as $cartItem) {
                    $insert = new \App\Transaction;
                    $insert->product_id = $cartItem->id;
                    $insert->receipt_id = $cartItem->receipt_id;
                    $insert->quantity = $cartItem->qty;
                    $insert->price= $cartItem->price;
                    $insert->save();
                }
            }
            DB::commit();
            Cart::destroy();
            return view('finishCheckout');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            return view('errorView')->withErrors($e->getMessage());
        }
            return abort(404);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you delete `use \Cart`

You can use `Cart::delete() or Cart::where(....)->delete()`

Comment: The `destroy()` `delete()` whatever you want to call it is not the issue. Sometimes this method (`destroy()` in my case) works, sometimes it does not. But is not the method fault, after multiple form submissions the request doesn't wait for the method to complete and makes a  new request instead. If I was to make only 1 click on the submit button the `checkout` method runs correctly.

Comment: Maybe empty cart

Comment: `Cart::destroy();` is the empty cart command and it does not work when I click the submit button multiple times. It works only if I click it once.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to prevent the double clicking client side. make a javascript function that `onSubmit` disables the submit button.

This way, the user will receive the response of the first call he made, not the last one (in case of double submit)

BTW, you can simulate a slow server. just add a `sleep(3)` at the start of the controller method.

Comment: With the `sleep(3)` I'm having the same issue the code fails on the same line BUT only on multiple form submissions. I was looking to learn why this happens before trying to solve it on the client side.

Comment: First request: checkout_logic + cart_destroy.  Second request: checkout_logic_with_no_cart(cause it was destroyed) -> error

Comment: First request doesn't `cart_destroy` when I click submit buttons multiple times. That is the issue. If I click the submit button once it does `cart_destroy` correctly.

Comment: @Victordb what you are saying is contradictory, can you put on your question the complete `checkout` code ?

Comment: I added some of it that has relevance to the question. Although is not an issue with the code as it works perfectly when I only submit the form once. The issue is when I click the submit buttons multiple times.

Comment: As i said, the result you're getting when submitting multiple time, is the latest request (404 100%). the first one worked correctly.

Comment: The first one doesn't do the `Cart::destroy();` I still have the products in my cart when I'm being redirected back with the validation error. When I submit the form with 1 click the  `Cart::destroy();` empties the shopping cart correctly. But when I submit with multiple clicks the   `Cart::destroy();` does not happen only the code above it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181745/discussion-between-n69s-and-victordb).

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that because you are clicking the button multiple times, on one of the requests it iterates through the cart content and then reaches the `Cart::destroy()` method, but then on other requests because it has already been it, it is failing the conditional and jumping straight to the `abort(404)` function.

If you are making the request with Ajax, it doesn't surprise me. With asynchronous HTTP requests if you click the button again it will create a new request and allow the previous to continue, rather than cancelling it. It should be your front end that when the button is clicked, while the request is in progress it disables the button so further requests cannot be made.

Comment: I am not making the request with Ajax, and the problem is that the first request STOPS right before `Cart::destroy()`. So the first request iterates through code (inserts into the database) and stops right at the `Cart::destroy()` for some reason.

Comment: It's possible that an exception is getting thrown. Check the logs and see if there is anything in there. You can also wrap the inserts in a database transaction so that if there is an exception, it reverts the database inserts.